# Applying Transport Rule only if the mail is text/plain and another if it is text/html

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, mime, email

I've been at this for quite some time now, not really getting it to work. Unfortunately I am only able to test on our Office365 account and changes take forever to propagate so I can test after changing rules..

The problem is as follows

My organisation wants a centralised signature added to all emails (this is easily fixed by adding a transport rule and "append a disclaimer ...")

Here is the kicker however, when the mail is sent as text/plain the nicely formatted HTML signature is wrapped (thats what we decided to do, so a signature is added at least) but it look **horrible**.

Is there any way of finding out if the mail is text/plain and then adding one signature and another if the mail is sent as HTML?

I've been playing around with rules and checking in the headers for `Content-Type` and trying to match against that but so far, no luck.

I believe Office365 runs Exchange 2010.

**edit**
Found the following on the Microsoft boards after some more digging:

> .. this would only work if you set your email to use POP or IMAP. Otherwise the content-type will not be viewable by the transport rule, and would therefore not work.

That explains why my attempts to look for `Content-Type` header failed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Exchange transport rules are just simply not flexible enough to handle the signature needs of most organizations, as you have found. The problem with searching email content with transport rules is that they search the rendered body, not the raw body. So if you're looking to match a MIME part header, you're out of luck.

At this point, you probably need to consider a third-party signature management product. See [Better Signature Management (Exchange-bound?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/455819/better-signature-management-exchange-bound)

Comment: Unfortunately we are on Office365 :(

Comment: Doh! I completely missed that part. Sorry.

Comment: Wait, Exclaimer does support Office 365 because it will update OWA signatures. You should check it out!

Comment: Indeed it does, I will have to look closer into it - Lesson learned, you shouldn't dismiss stuff too fast!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the right Content-Type header isn't easy to catch. In fact, it's seen only when you use web mail (or if you know where to dig in Exchange logs). It's not the one you see in your Mail app. The header is always

`Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"`

There's nothing in the other headers which would help to distinguish the forma. Yes they do show X-Mailer, and another difference is that Message-ID ends either with XXX123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM or your own domain depending if you use Outlook connector or other mail client (Mail.app on both iOS and macOS gave own domain name), but that's about it.

To be honest, when I was testing a plain text disclaimer, I wasn't able to add a new line there, so now I'm just going with hand-wavey approach...